The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher. Any Solution?
The plugin flutter_screen_recording uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2101 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_screen_recording' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I Change the Build Gradle File kotlin Version is 1.7.10 and 1.8.20 but faced same Problem again

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
